# How to increase visual length of form text field in Word?

Tags: ms-word, textfield

When a form text field is inserted in a Word document, the grey shaded length is about 5 characters long. How can this length be increased?

Answer (score 0):

Allthough it is a rather crude measure (and I don't recommend it), you can set "Properties -> Default Text" to as many blanks as you want the size. But this comes for a price: as long as you move into the field by pressing TAB, all blanks are selected and get typed over. When you use the mouse, you click the cursor anywhere into the field and start typing ... so your entry might be pre and post fixed by a number of blanks that you have to trim away in e.g. an exit macro.

I recommend old form fields as the last resort (i.e. there must be a good reason to use them) and would prefer (in that order)

- native Word2010/2007 fields (text or Rich text - perhaps not backwords compatible)
- legacy ActiveX fields (compatible with W2003)
- Legacy (old) form fields

Comment: The problem with `ActiveX` fields is that they bring up a warning when you first open the document.

Comment: ActiveX components on their own normally don't produce a warning; this most often happens in combination with VBA ... see chapter "ActiveX-control settings explained" in http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-HA010354314.aspx